# asynchronous call on uisearchbar on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I need to set an asynchronous call for research on uisearchbar on Tableview on remote server?
I follow this tutorial to implement the searchbar on tableview but in this tutorial the list of element is static, while in my case I need to search on remote server.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the delegate method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

To send your request and make it auto complete, but i would use the

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

And in this method make a post or get request to your webservice.

Use ASIHTTPRequest for it or RestKit.
I think you know how to do that?

Comment: No i don't know. can you help me?

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ is a library wich you can use to GET data of a webservice. You want a search on a remote server right? Than you have to do a request to the server when the user clicks search. Download the classes, read the instructions on how to install. They also have a very nice example: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use i think you can complete it further if not comment =]